# Как вставлять по несколько ячеек сразу?

Tags: javascript, html

Я создаю таблицу в JS при помощи не сложной функции, но проблема в том, что в каждую строку вставляется только по одной ячейке, как мне сделать чтобы в каждую вставилось по 8? Сейчас пришел к такому коду, пробовал сделать еще один for внутри первого, но это не помогло.

```js
function createChessPlate () {
    let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody')
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        let th = document.createElement('th');
        tbody.append(tr);
        tr.append(th);

    }
}

createChessPlate()
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: orangered;
}

.tools-panel{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: max-content;
    gap: 2.5px;
}

.tools-panel__inputs{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2.5px;
}

.tools-panel__buttons{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

input{
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    border: solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

button{
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    border: solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 45%;
    height: 20px;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus, button:focus{
    outline: none;
}

th {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chess Plate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tools-panel">
        <div class="tools-panel__inputs">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Number of rows...">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Number of cells in one row...">
        </div>

        <div class="tools-panel__buttons">
            <button>Create</button>
            <button>Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Всё правильно ещё один цикл внутри, в нем создавай `th` и добавляй `tr.append(th)` после этого цикла `tbody.append(tr)`

Comment: @Rudi спасибо, действительно работает. Могли бы, Вы объяснить почему не сработал мой вариант со вторым циклом? https://codepen.io/dhelfy/pen/LYrPbez

Comment: @dhelfy, возможно, что Вам будет полезен следующий [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1389546/265406).

Comment: Потому что 8  раз один и тот же элемент `th` добавляешь, а не создаёшь 8 элементов..